# Combining time and time zone columns in data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I've got a csv file with trip data. Each row specifies where the trip started (`origin`), where the trip ended (`destination`), as well as the starting time (`depart_time`) and ending time of the trip (`arrival_time`). The `depart_time` and `arrival_time` are in **local** times. Columns `depart_time_zone` and `arrival_time_zone` specify the corresponding time zones of the origin and destination respectively.

Example data:

```
origin,destination,depart_time,depart_time_zone,arrival_time,arrival_time_zone
A,B,04/04/2023 08:01,GMT-04:00,04/04/2023 09:02,GMT-04:00
C,D,04/04/2023 09:20,GMT-04:00,04/04/2023 16:48,GMT-05:00
```

I'd like to combine the time and time_zone columns. For that I used the following function:

```
data = pd.read_csv('trips.csv', parse_dates={'depart' : ['depart_time','depart_time_zone'],'arrive' : ['arrival_time','arrival_time_zone']})
```

This seems to accomplish my goal. However, notice from the first line in this CSV that the `depart_time=04/04/2023 08:00` and `depart_time_zone=GMT-04:00`
When looking at the output of the above command, I get: `depart=2023-04-04 08:00:00+04:00`. Notice the `-04` changed into `+04`. This seems incorrect?

Comment: Seems like a bug. It works as expected in Pandas 2.0.3 but not Pandas 1.5.3.

Comment: @wjandrea I confirm your observation. Updating to Pandas 2.03 resolves this issue. For reference, I was using pandas 1.4.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to parse the dates after loading the CSV, for example:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

df["depart"] = pd.to_datetime(df["depart_time"] + " " + df["depart_time_zone"])    # you can add dayfirst=True/False (depends on your data)
df["arrival"] = pd.to_datetime(df["arrival_time"] + " " + df["arrival_time_zone"])

print(df[["origin", "destination", "depart", "arrival"]])
```

Prints:

```
  origin destination                    depart                    arrival
0      A           B 2023-04-04 08:01:00-04:00  2023-04-04 09:02:00-04:00
1      C           D 2023-04-04 09:20:00-04:00  2023-04-04 16:48:00-05:00
```

Comment: This also gets the wrong result on Pandas 1.5.3, but it works properly in Pandas 2.0.3, as does OP's code. So it seems like the problem is actually a bug. Or were you able to reproduce the issue in a different version of Pandas?

Comment: @wjandrea I'm using `pandas==2.0.3` So yes, seems like a bug in previous versions.